# The Stanley family in Jamaica and England

Tags: england, jamaica

I'm looking for information about the Stanley family who apparently owned a plantation in Jamaica.  I'm trying to find out if this family was part of my husband's great grandfather's family. My husband's great grandfather, James Lynn Adams (March 17, 1876-1925), came to Washington state around 1910 from Ontario, Canada.  He married Rita Olga Eichler (1893-1957).

Talking to my mother in law, apparently this wasn't his real name.  His name was Richard Lebret Brougham Stanley.  His family used to lived in Ontario, Canada.  She doesn't know if everything in this story is correct.  She mentioned his parents separated from their family in England and changed their last name to Adams.  Richard's mother's last name was Stanley and she came from a wealthy family who owned plantations in Jamaica. He may had a sister named Victoria who used to travel around the world and probably worked for the government in the USA or Canada.

When I started searching for this information, I found Henry Stanley (1766-1826) who owned plantations in Jamaica.  He left a will where one of his witnesses was George Brougham, his servant. As I mentioned, Richard's father's last name was Brougham.

I'm wondering if anyone can give me any information which can help me find Richard's family in England?